# Getting blob data from a JSON into a MySQL table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdf, blob

I have a problem I am hoping someone can help with. I am capturing some information on Cognito forms. Right now it is basic info but will add more. It is a form for students to send their name, contact info, and resume. The Cognito form allows upload of a doc or pdf file. An sends the data as JSON data to an intermediary php file (below) that parses it and inserts it into mysql table 'students'.

The code below works and I am able to receive the data and it goes into the table. The pdf resume field says BLOB -5B so I know something went int there. The trouble is that I cannot seem to read it. I suspect I am not taking the right part of the JSON data.

Do I bind the whole Resume object `$contact->{'Resume'}` ?
or should it be `$contact->{'Resume'}-->{'somethingelse'}` ?

My structure for the resume blob field is mediumblob null is Yes default null

```
<?php  
    $json = file_get_contents("php://input");  

    if (empty($json)) {  
        echo "No data payload";  
        die;  
    }  

$host="db5000312294.hosting-data.io";
$user="xxx";
$password="xxx";
$dbname="xxx";

    $contact = json_decode($json);  
    if ($contact == null && json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {  
        echo "Error reading JSON: " . json_last_error();  
    }  

    $mysqli = new mysqli("$host", "$user", "$password","$dbname");  
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {  
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;  
        die;  
    }  

    $query = "insert into students (fname,lname,phone,email,resume,position) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";  
    if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query))) {  
        echo "Prepare failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;  
        die;  
    }  

    if (!($stmt->bind_param("ssssss",   
        $contact->{'Name'}->{'First'},   
        $contact->{'Name'}->{'Last'},  
        $contact->{'Phone'},  
        $contact->{'Email'},  
    $contact->{'Resume'}, 
        $contact->{'WhatPositionAreYouApplyingFor'}))) {  

        echo "Bind failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;  
    }  

    if (!($stmt->execute())) {  
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;      
    }  
?>
This is what the JSON section looks like
    "Resume": [
        {
          "ContentType": "application/pdf",
          "Id": "F-qIr7WOAa2Yeh9ZnzPcvspk",
          "IsEncrypted": false,
          "Name": "Principal etfs.pdf",
          "Size": 188451,
          "File": "https://services.cognitoforms.com/fa/SVh77OiVmEK-J1ZtGNTRAQ?token=RUN_uR__rdZy_FTNnav8GGP6uEHoT7vYR2Yo9uccQxyfX4sIDMcqaOw52U27pIggHrjsfuQK0tBXYiiYqdPDGw$$"
        }
      ],
```

Keeping the pdf outside of the database and only saving the link is not an option since it is uploaded on Cognito and the JSON is passed to me.

Comment: What does `var_dump` say?

Comment: @tadman
There is something going into the blob field. When I add a new record, I see blob -5B

I added this to the bottom of my php script to send the contents to a text file:

$file = 'somefile.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $contact->{'Resume'}->{'File'});

but it creates an empty text.

Comment: Tip: Check the structure with `var_dump`.

Comment: This is my raw JSON data. When I add the whole JSON object 'Resume' to my 'filename' field, it says 'Array' . Do you know how I can bind the part of the array that contains the file?

https://webhook.site/#!/11347ffa-9482-40d6-8456-87df7bd84055/d49a2aa3-75f2-419c-a4b3-b1f1b4d557b5/1

Comment: When I var_dump, this is the Resume section -
`code
["Resume"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#21 (6) {
      ["ContentType"]=>
      string(15) "application/pdf"
      ["Id"]=>
      string(24) "F-WYxm!976WoKvFdjCNWEf5!"
      ["IsEncrypted"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["Name"]=>
      string(23) "James-T--DiGiovanni.pdf"
      ["Size"]=>
      int(53809)
      ["File"]=>
      string(154) "https://services.cognitoforms.com/fa/SVh77OiVmEK-J1ZtGNTRAQ?token=5ryyuzBRqgeCJQaQv6oMSkIPfd4hRPo7MusMIxbRWTFDfFkHWGi96R10mR-3PovTagY5Ar1V7HX4evYJiNTCPA$$"
    }
  }
`

Comment: Well there you go. Looks like a URL you need to fetch to get it, or just store the URL if that's persisted for you.